# How to replace /n to linebreaks in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to replace every `/n` to a `<br>` tag in `ReactJS`. In my `note.note` object there is a string with multiple `/n` in it.

**example note.note:** `test\ntest\ntest`

What I have tried in `ReactJS`:

```
{
  note.note.split('\n').map(function( item, idx) {
    return (
        <span key={idx}>
          {item}
          <br/>
        </span>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? Seems like your logic is sound: https://jsfiddle.net/sn2qkgzs/1/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your code works well:

```
{
    note.note.split("\n").map(function(item, idx) {
        return (
            <span key={idx}>
                {item}
                <br/>
            </span>
         )
    })
}
```

The OP problem was with the backend which returns `\\n` and shows as `\n` in the `XHR preview` tab

Comment: yeah seems like replacing would be easier/cleaner, than splitting it up and reassembling it

Comment: @Jayce444 It's the commonly used way of doing a full replace in Javascript `s.split("\n").join("<br/>")`, for example

Comment: What is the difference with my method here? the only thing i see different is the .text after note.note ?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Good to know!

Comment: note.note.split('\n').join('<br/>')   this also doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JimPeeters If the second doesn't work there is an error somewhere else. [Example fiddle of it working](https://jsfiddle.net/sn2qkgzs/1/)

Comment: Your solution works. The problem was with me because it came back '//n' from my backend but it showed as '/n' in my XHR preview tab

Answer (score 148):

An alternative to this would be to use css to display it with line breaks. This also makes it easier to copy and paste with the original line breaks as well as distinguishing between one break (`\n`) and two breaks (`\n\n`).

Just add the style `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your element.

```
<div style={{whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"}}>{note.note}</div>
```

There are additional white-space options if that doesn't do exactly what you'd like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Much better; there is already a CSS solution to do this & constructing a bunch of DOM elements to render a text string as-is, is overkill IMO

Comment: There are instances when you want to split the text to create things like bullets, but for situations where you are outputting text that was entered via a textarea form input, this method is simple, repeatable and sooooo efficient. So glad I read through a few of the comments first because I was about to dive headfirst into the split solution - thanks.

Comment: definitely the best answer

Answer (score 5):

I just want to share this function I've been using for quite some time. It is similar to Jim Peeters' answer but no parent tags generated, just turning the `\n` to `<br key="<index here>" />`.

```
import React from 'react'

export const escapedNewLineToLineBreakTag = (string) => {
  return string.split('\n').map((item, index) => {
    return (index === 0) ? item : [<br key={index} />, item]
  })
}
```

You can also convert this to a bit of a long one-liner by omitting `return` and curly brackets.

```
export const escapedNewLineToLineBreakTag = (string) => string.split('\n').map((item, index) => (index === 0) ? item : [<br key={index} />, item])
```

**Disclaimer**: The logic behind is not from me but I can't remember where I found it. I just turned it into function form.

Answer (score 2):

A little update for React newer versions

```
{
  note.note
    .split('\n')
    .map((item, idx) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={idx}>
          {item}
          <br />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
{
    note.note.split('\n').map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <span key={idx}>
            {item}
            <br/>
          </span>
        );
    })
}
```