# Put breakpoint once the newline is determined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use React.js with Typescript.
I have a component which renders in this way:

```
<div class="test">
   Hello dear
   Sam
</div>
```

What I want is to tell the code manually that once `"\n"` is detected in class `"test"`, put `<br/>` in it. Is it possible to do somehow using css / js?
Because on web page the content of div is one line, I want to break it on two.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use something like `{text.split('\n').map(line => [line, <br/>]).flat()}` (there's going to be a `<br/>` at the end though. Or you can use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace /n to linebreaks in react.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418024/how-to-replace-n-to-linebreaks-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [white-space: pre-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) after making your string separated with `\n` i.e. `"Hello dear\nSam"`:

```js
const text = "Hello dear\nSam"

function App() {
  return <div class="pre-line">{text}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```css
.pre-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```